# Fedora: Stylus Pen not working

Tags: fedora, stylus-pen

I have an acer switch alpha, and both Ubuntu and Debian worked flawlessly with the stylus. But I cannot get it to work at all on Fedora which is my preferred OS. 
What works:
Hovering
Clicking on anything related to the gnome-shell (settings, activity bar, title bar) But nothing inside windows aside from the settings application so far.

Very odd behavior, am I missing some libraries?

Honestly the amount of time I waste debugging Fedora over the last few years is a bit much. Never had as many problems on Ubuntu or Debian will probably just swap considering how utterly unreliable Fedora has become.

Answer (score 4):

As of Fedora 25, the distro defaults to booting into a Wayland-powered desktop. Pens are not well supported under Wayland at the moment; only native GTK3 applications such as the shell and GNOME Control Center will react to pen input (many applications either still use GTK2 or another toolkit like Qt).

Until the situation improves, I would recommend using the "gear" icon on the login screen to change your session from "GNOME" to "GNOME on Xorg". The pen should return to functioning as it has in the past.